# Install windows xp 64bit from DOS

Tags: windows-xp, installation, dos, mode

I have Windows XP 64bit extracted from ISO file. I know 32 bit Windows XP can be installed from DOS using winnt.exe. So I want to install Windows XP 64bit from DOS but I don't know how to do that? (I boot into DOS mode from Windows 98 bootable CD).

So please tell me how can I install Windows XP 64bit from DOS mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP 64 bit cannot be installed from MS-DOS or a command line because it doesn't include the winnt.exe. It installs by booting directly from a disk. Not sure why Microsoft would choose to change that but that's the way it is.

Perhaps you can set your drive to boot from the .ISO?